# vb.net you have an error in your sql syntax;

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I have got this error after  i'm click Save button, but event on button work properly.  I know there must be error in one of the queries below, but i'm not sure which one .... Please review my code and i hope you can answer ASAP. Thanks

Error

```
you have an error in your sql syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near " at line 1
```

Here's my code.

```
Private Sub add_petugas()
    Try
        sql = "INSERT INTO petugas(kd_petugas, nm_petugas, j_kel, almt_petugas, tlp_petugas, user, password, hak_akses) VALUES('" & txtKode.Text & "', '" & txtNama.Text & "', '" & cmbSex.Text & "', '" & txtAlamat.Text & "', '" & txtTelepon.Text & "', '" & txtUsername.Text & "', '" & txtPassword.Text & "', '" & txtHak.Text & "')"
        openDB()
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)
        Dim i As Integer
        i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
        If i > 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Data petugas berhasil ditambahkan", "Daftar", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Data petugas gagal ditambahkan", "Daftar", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        cmd.Dispose()
        conn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub update_petugas()
    Try
        sql = "UPDATE petugas SET kd_petugas ='" & txtKode.Text & "', nm_petugas = '" & txtNama.Text & "', j_kel = '" & cmbSex.Text & "', almt_petugas = '" & txtAlamat.Text & "', tlp_petugas = '" & txtTelepon.Text & "', user = '" & txtUsername.Text & "', password = '" & txtPassword.Text & "', hak_akses = '" & txtHak.Text & "' WHERE kd_petugas = " & txtKode.Text & ""
        openDB()
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)
        Dim i As Integer
        i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
        If i > 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Data petugas berhasil diupdate", "Update", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Data petugas gagal diupdate", "Update", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        cmd.Dispose()
        conn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: You're missing single quotes around the variable you're using in the `WHERE` clause of your `UPDATE` query.

Comment: @MikeW i'm already try to fix that with single quotes but the error still coming ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like some quotes got left out near the end.

```
WHERE kd_petugas = " & txtKode.Text & ""
```

to

```
WHERE kd_petugas = '" & txtKode.Text & "'"
```

Comment: That may well be the case but if you use parameters then you never have to worry about single quotes or other delimiters.  Adding those single quotes may make this code work but the "proper" solution is to use parameters.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - I agree 100%!

Comment: @jmcilhinney i'm already try this but the error still coming. I'm still don't understand "parameters" since this is my school exam and i'm still new in vb.net . If u don't mind, can u explain "parameters" using my code ?

Comment: How about you follow the link I provided in my answer below, where I have already explained parameters in a Blog post specifically so that I don't have to keep explaining it over and over to every single person?

Comment: @Drewness Thanks, it's worked. Looks like my other queries that owns the problem.

Comment: If you use parameters then you can't forget single quotes because you don't have to use single quotes but, most importantly, you are safe from SQL injection.

Comment: @Dika - You're welcome, glad to help. I **really** would look at [jmcilhinney's blog](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html) too.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, 
    ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = Chr(13) Then
        CMD = New OdbcCommand(String.Format("select * from petugas where nama='" & TextBox1.Text & "', and kode_petugas='" & MenuUtama.Panel1.Text & "'"), CONN)
        RD = CMD.ExecuteReader
        RD.Read()
        If RD.HasRows Then
            TextBox2.Text = True
            TextBox2.Focus()
        Else
            MsgBox("Anda tidak berhak mengganti password disini")
            TextBox1.Focus()
        End If
    End If
```